# How can sort by odd,even row?

Tags: c#, arrays

I hava jagged Array
I want sort first,third row ascending order and second,fourth row descending order

```
public class JaggedArrayTest {
  public static void Main() {
    int[][] arr = new int[4][] {
      new int[] {
          11,
          78,
          56,
          21
        },
        new int[] {
          2,
          7,
          5,
          6
        },
        new int[] {
          8,
          3,
          9,
          12
        },
        new int[] {
          1,
          10,
          19,
          17
        }
    };
    // Traverse array elements  
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].Length; j++) {
        System.Console.Write(arr[i][j] + "    ");
      }
      System.Console.WriteLine();
    }
  }
}
```

I want output like this

```
11, 21, 56, 78 
7, 6, 5,2
3, 8,9,12
19,17,10,1
```

Comment: So you have an array of array of int, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Algo:-

- Loop through each row.
- Use Array.Sort() to sort each row

for(int row = 0; row < arr.Length; row++)
{
Array.Sort(arr[row]);
}

Answer (score 1):

Although a little *"allocatey"*, this can be done with *linq* and the [*remainder operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-) (to test for odd or even) fairly easily

> The remainder operator ``% computes the remainder after dividing its
> left-hand operand by its right-hand operand.

```
var results = arr.Select((values, i) 
   => (i % 2 == 0 ? values.OrderBy(x => x) : values.OrderByDescending(x => x)).ToArray())
   .ToArray();

foreach (var values in results)
   Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ",values));
```

Or an in situ, less *"allocatey"*, and more idiomatic approach

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
   Array.Sort(arr[i]);
   if(i % 2 != 0)
      Array.Reverse(arr[i]); 
}
```

**Output**

```
11, 21, 56, 78
7, 6, 5, 2
3, 8, 9, 12
19, 17, 10, 1
```